# Why prefer $MgSO_4$ over $MgCl_2$ in recipies

Tags: protocol, biochemistry

Many molecular biology recipes use MgSO<sub>4</sub> (and not MgCl<sub>2</sub>). Is there indeed a preference? If so, why?

Comment: Can you specify which recipes you mean? I am aware of a number of polymerases like Pfu which prefer $ MgSO_4 $. I haven't found a reference for that now, but its probably the same: The chloride ion interferes with the enzymes reaction.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is its the solubility properties of the anions.

Chloride ions can precipitate with some metals that might appear in a complicated buffer or medium. And yes they could even compete with enzyme binding.  Sulfate will remain in solution with just about anything.

There are exceptions, but if you're making a buffer you're probably going to do better if you use the [general solubility rules](http://www.csudh.edu/oliver/chemdata/solrules.htm).

Comment: Are you sure about the insoluble chloride salts? I recall only a handfull of them, mostly with ions, which are not common in cells like titanium or silver. For sulphate I agree completely.

Comment: Although calcium sulphate is only sparingly soluble.

Comment: added a link... this is chem 101 so nearly every book has a mention of some form of counter-ion solubility rules.

Comment: @AlanBoyd A number of sulphates is nearly insoluble.